# How do I initialize this anonymous function?

Tags: c#, list, initialization

```
        var groups = new List<Group>
        {
           new Group{
               Name = "Train", 
               Members = new List<Colleague>{
                   {FirstName = "Thomas", LastName = "Tank"},
                   {FirstName = "Honey", LastName = "Booboo"}
               }  
           }, 
           new Group{Name = "Bus"}
        };
```

I am getting a red underline under 'FirstName' and 'LastName'... meaning that I've initialised it wrong...

**How can I initialise that (Colleague) List?** I think I am incorrectly initialising that list (Members)...

**Edit**: To make things clearer,

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Colleague> Members { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**: Following up discussion with Kirk Woll:

This is what I did with your advice. Members is null though...

```
var groups = new List<Group>
        {
           new Group
           {
               Name = "Train", 
               Members = new List<Colleague>{
                   new Colleague { FirstName = "Thomas", LastName = "Tank" },
                   new Colleague { FirstName = "Jet", LastName = "Starr" }
               }

           }, 
           new Group{Name = "Bus"}
        };
```

To summarise, there's a breakpoint after the initialisation of groups. Each Group (x2) has Name defined, but Members = null in the first Group ('Train'). Members must be initialised! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
Members = new List<Colleague>
{
    new Colleague { FirstName = "Thomas", LastName = "Tank" },
    new Colleague { FirstName = "Honey", LastName = "Booboo" }
}
```

Since it's a list of `Colleague` to which you're trying to add it.

Comment: Do you mean like,
    Members = new List<Colleague>{
                       new Colleague { FirstName = "Thomas", LastName = "Tank" }} ? I've just tried this, but when I stop there using a breakpoint, Members is null.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by setting the breakpoint -- where did you set it?  If you set it in this block of code then yes -- `Members` will still be null.  It won't be non-null until after this entire initializer expression evaluates.

Comment: I've set the breakpoint after the initialisation of groups. So at the breakpoint, each Group has a Name, but 'Train's Members is null.

Comment: It can't be.  Perhaps edit your question and append your now compilable example.